# SQL to track customer's journey

Tags: sql, analytics

I have data of users visiting a website, then they register, sign in and continue. So when they land on the page, the `user_id` will be null. Once the user registers, a `user_id` is generated from the tracker. For example.

```
user_id   IP-address      page_url         domain_id   location
null      192.45.34.23    Landing page     A           ABC
null      192.45.34.23    Welcome page     A           ABC
null      192.45.34.23    FAQ              A           ABC
null      192.45.34.23    Help             A           ABC
null      178.34.12.54    Landing page     A           ABC
12345     192.45.34.23    Sign up          A           ABC
12345     192.45.34.23    Sign in-page1    A           ABC
12345     178.34.12.54    Sign in-page 2   A           ABC
```

When tracking a customer's journey, I need to map the `user_id` with null to ones after being assigned. 
So in the table, top5 user id has to be `12345` if the IP address and `domain_id` are same.

user `12345` has 2 IP-address so when the IP address or domain_id matches, the user id has to be mapped.

The output should be like below

```
user_id   IP-address      page_url         domain_id     location
12345     192.45.34.23    Landing page     A             ABC
12345     192.45.34.23    Welcome page     A             ABC
12345     192.45.34.23    FAQ              A             ABC
12345     192.45.34.23    Help             A             ABC
12345     178.34.12.54    Landing page     A             ABC
12345     192.45.34.23    Sign up          A             ABC
12345     192.45.34.23    Sing in-page 1   A             ABC
12345     178.34.12.54    Sign in-page 2   A             ABC
```

Comment: I'd look at using Google Sheets' GA plugin to pull in the data, then using formula(s) in the Sheet to manipulate the data. GA is not going to do this for you because it logs what it sees in real time, it doesn't go back and tidy up afterwards.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: Why has `12345` two IP addresses, `192.45.34.23` and `178.34.12.54`?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?  This uses the T-SQL syntax for SQL Server; though should be similar to what you'd need for most other database engines.

```
declare @example table
(
  Id bigint not null identity(1,1)
  , [user_id] bigint 
  , [IP-address] nvarchar(15) not null
  , page_url nvarchar(1024) not null
  , domain_id  nvarchar(32) not null
  , location nvarchar(32) not null
)

insert @example([user_id],   [IP-address], page_url, domain_id, location)
values (null   , '192.45.34.23', 'Landing page'  , 'A', 'ABC')
     , (null   , '192.45.34.23', 'Welcome page'  , 'A', 'ABC')
     , (null   , '192.45.34.23', 'FAQ'           , 'A', 'ABC')
     , (null   , '192.45.34.23', 'Help'          , 'A', 'ABC')
     , (null   , '178.34.12.54', 'Landing page'  , 'A', 'ABC')
     , (12345  , '192.45.34.23', 'Sign up'       , 'A', 'ABC')
     , (null   , '123.1.2.3'   , 'Help'          , 'B', 'ABC')
     , (12345  , '192.45.34.23', 'Sign in-page1' , 'A', 'ABC')
     , (12345  , '178.34.12.54', 'Sign in-page 2', 'A', 'ABC')
     , (98765  , '123.1.2.3'   , 'Help'          , 'B', 'ABC')

select Id
, coalesce
(
    [user_id]
    ,
    (
        select top 1 [user_id] 
        from @example b
        where [user_id] is not null
        and b.Id > a.Id 
        and
        (
            b.[IP-address] = a.[IP-address]
            or b.domain_id = a.domain_id
        )
        order by Id
    )
)      [user_id]
,      [IP-address]
,      page_url
,      domain_id
,      location
from @example a
```

i.e. We select all rows from the table, but where the user id is not populated we derive it from the later entries using the criteria you gave (i.e. matching on domain or IP).

You've not specified it in your criteria, but I've taken the liberty of adding an ID field and using that to ensure that the entry we fetch is a later entry, and is the first entry to match.  This assumes that nulls will only occur before a user logs in (i.e. a user won't log out and continue to access the site).  The reason for including this rather than taking any match is I've assumed that potentially over time the same IP may be reassigned to a different user; so this gives you a best guess at which of the multiple matches is most likely to be the user you're after.